# I want to show img in my template from database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i want to show image from `model.py` file in `user` app where i uplode my image.

this is `user.model.py` file

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}  profile.'
    
    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height>300 or img.width > 300:
            img.thumbnail( (300,300) )
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

`blog.model.py`(blog is another app) .

this is `blog.model.py` file

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="enter within 100 charecter")
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # this is for show demo form admin site (if you use this than genarate a button for demo )
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

And this is my class base view funcatin in `blog` app Whose template name is `home.html`.

this is `blog.view.py` file

**view.py**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ip'] = self.request.session.get('ip', 0)
        return context
```

**home.html**

I show you only image tag.

```
{% for post in posts %}
<img style="height: 80px; width: 80px; float: left;" class=" img-circle account-img " src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
 {% endfor %}
```

What i write code in template this is doesn't show image.

THis is my home.html page [[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp8Na.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp8Na.png)

I need to show image from `user.model.py` file where `image` is tabel row in home.html file.
If you want anything plase tell me. thankyou....

Comment: IMHO should be just `src="{{ post.author.image.url }}"`

Comment: Your code looks fine at first glance. Have you double-checked if the model relationships are correctly saved? For example, in the command line, can you retrieve post.author.profile.image.url for your posts?